# Remote WMI not working when hosted as Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi, dcom

I am working on Remote WMI. I have done all DCOM settings, CIMV2 and WMI settings for particular User. When I run the application as console app, it works fine and fetches me the data. But when I host the same as Windows service, it is throwing exception as

```
Message:  Error Message: Access is denied. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) 
Inner Exception Message:  Stack Trace:    
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    
at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)    
at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()    
at RemoteWMIRule.BackupServerRule..ctor()
```

Comment: @Sumon Banerjee: if you edited this post already, you could also have improved formatting and add WMI and DCOM tags

Comment: @user3323400: welcome on Stackoverflow. Please try to use the code formatting features and use the preview. Try making your question readable. Also, be specific on tags. You can try the keywords and abbreviations used in your question. Stackoverflow will make suggestions if the tags already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Got Solved by adding Network and Network Service in DCOM Configurations. But still the problem persists in Windows Server 2008 R2 OS. Anything OS specific to be done???!!